# How can I safely use angular2-logger in Production

Tags: javascript, angular, production-environment

I'm looking for a logging framework for my Angular 2 application with the following goals.

- Instead of using console.log do something like this._logger.log(msg). This way I can later update _logger to ship the logs to backend or do whatever I want with the logs.
- Set logging levels and/or have additional controls

I've come across [angular2-logger](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger). But as per it's documentation it's not ready for Production use yet. How can I safely use this for production?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-logger,

According to the description, it has Production mode by configuration:

`Log.setProductionMode();`

I am working to integrate it and if more information, I will update.